# How perform a drag (based in X,Y mouse coordinates) on Android using AccessibilityService?

Tags: java, c#, android, accessibilityservice, mouse-coordinates

I want know how to perform a drag on android based in X, Y mouse coordinates? consider as two simple examples, the Team Viewer/QuickSupport drawing the "password pattern" on remote smartphone and the Pen of Windows Paint respectively.

[image]

[image]

All that i'm able of make is [simulate touch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51706446/9708179) (with `dispatchGesture()` and also `AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK`).

I found these relevants links, but not know if they can be useful:

- [Perform swipe on screen using AccessibilityService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44448362/9708179)
- [**Example 1**](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription)
- [**Continued gestures**](https://eventandtech.blogspot.com/p/fingerprint-gestures-accessibility.html)

Below is my working code that is used to send mouse coordinates (inside of `PictureBox` control) to remote phone and simulate touch.

**Windows Forms Application:**

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvConnections.SelectedItems)
    {
        // Remote screen resolution
        string[] tokens = item.SubItems[5].Text.Split('x'); // Ex: 1080x1920

        int xClick = (e.X * int.Parse(tokens[0].ToString())) / (pictureBox1.Size.Width);
        int yClick = (e.Y * int.Parse(tokens[1].ToString())) / (pictureBox1.Size.Height);

        Client client = (Client)item.Tag;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            client.sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TOUCH" + xClick + "<|>" + yClick + Environment.NewLine));
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

My last attempt was a "swipe screen" using mouse coordinates (C# Windows Forms Application) and a custom android routine (with reference to code of "swipe screen" linked above), respectively:

```
private Point mdownPoint = new Point();

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvConnections.SelectedItems)
    {
        // Remote screen resolution
        string[] tokens = item.SubItems[5].Text.Split('x'); // Ex: 1080x1920

        Client client = (Client)item.Tag;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            xClick = (e.X * int.Parse(tokens[0].ToString())) / (pictureBox1.Size.Width); 
            yClick = (e.Y * int.Parse(tokens[1].ToString())) / (pictureBox1.Size.Height);

            // Saving start position:

            mdownPoint.X = xClick; 
            mdownPoint.Y = yClick; 

            client.sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("TOUCH" + xClick + "<|>" + yClick + Environment.NewLine));
        }
    }
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lvConnections.SelectedItems)
    {
        // Remote screen resolution
        string[] tokens = item.SubItems[5].Text.Split('x'); // Ex: 1080x1920

        Client client = (Client)item.Tag;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            xClick = (e.X * int.Parse(tokens[0].ToString())) / (pictureBox1.Size.Width);
            yClick = (e.Y * int.Parse(tokens[1].ToString())) / (pictureBox1.Size.Height);

            client.sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MOUSESWIPESCREEN" + mdownPoint.X + "<|>" + mdownPoint.Y + "<|>" + xClick + "<|>" + yClick + Environment.NewLine));
        }
    }
}
```

android *AccessibilityService*:

```
public void Swipe(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int time) {

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    System.out.println(" ======= Swipe =======");

    GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(x1, y1);
    path.lineTo(x2, y2);

    gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 100, time));
    dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), new GestureResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
            System.out.println("SWIPE Gesture Completed :D");
            super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
        }
    }, null);
}

}
```

that produces the following result (but still not is able to draw "pattern password" like TeamViewer for example). But like said on comment below, I think that with a similar approach this can be achieved using [Continued gestures](https://eventandtech.blogspot.com/p/fingerprint-gestures-accessibility.html) probably. Any suggestions in this direction will be welcome.

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit 2:**

Definitely, the solution is [continued gestures](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/GestureDescription.StrokeDescription#continueStroke(android.graphics.Path,%20long,%20long,%20boolean)) like said on previous **Edit**.

- [**Simulating joystick movement using AccessibilityService**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57195814/simulating-joystick-movement-using-accessibilityservice)
- [**Why the continueStroke function is not work**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389826/why-the-continuestroke-function-is-not-work)

And below is a supposed fixed code that i found [here](http://www.mysql5.com/thread-496-1-1.html) =>

*android AccessibilityService:*

```
// Simulates an L-shaped drag path: 200 pixels right, then 200 pixels down.
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(200,200);
path.lineTo(400,200);

final GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 500, true);

// The starting point of the second path must match
// the ending point of the first path.
Path path2 = new Path();
path2.moveTo(400,200);
path2.lineTo(400,400);

final GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd2 = sd.continueStroke(path2, 0, 500, false); // 0.5 second

HongBaoService.mService.dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd).build(), new AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback(){

@Override
public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription){
super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
HongBaoService.mService.dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd2).build(),null,null);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription){
super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
}
},null);
```

Then, my doubt is: **how send correctly mouse coordinates for code above, of the way that can perform drag to any direction?** Some idea?

---

**Edit 3:**

I found two routines that are used to perform drag, but they are using [UiAutomation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html) + [`injectInputEvent()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159265/how-to-inject-click-event-with-android-uiautomation-injectinputevent). AFAIK, injection of event works only in a system app like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33443102/9708179) and [here](https://gist.github.com/oneyoung/a14c99856c3984263734) and i not want it.

This are routines found:

- [public boolean swipe(int downX, int downY, int upX, int upY, int steps, boolean drag)](https://github.com/USC-NSL/PUMA/blob/2545e58b22f421f387a52f73fa893cf7716bab3c/src/nsl/stg/uiautomator/core/MyInteractionController.java#L403)
- [public boolean swipe(Point[] segments, int segmentSteps)](https://github.com/USC-NSL/PUMA/blob/2545e58b22f421f387a52f73fa893cf7716bab3c/src/nsl/stg/uiautomator/core/MyInteractionController.java#L442)

Then to achieve my goal, i think that 2rd routine is more appropriated to use (following the logic, excluding event injection) with code showed on **Edit 2** and send all points of `pictureBox1_MouseDown` and `pictureBox1_MouseMove` (C# Windows Forms Application) respectively to fill `Point[]` dynamically and on `pictureBox1_MouseUp` send cmd to execute the routine and use this array filled. If you have a idea to 1st routine, let me know :D.

If after read this **Edit** you have a possible solution, show me in a answer please, while i will try and test this idea.

Comment: TeamViewer is not using the accessibility framework, most likely. They have special deals with device manufacturers, which is why their product is not available for all devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you. But i think that [`StrokeDescription.continueStroke()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/GestureDescription.StrokeDescription.html#continueStroke(android.graphics.Path,%20long,%20long,%20boolean)) can be a probable solution. See section **Continued gestures** [here](https://eventandtech.blogspot.com/p/fingerprint-gestures-accessibility.html).

Comment: Regarding your first aproach. `pictureBox1_MouseDown` must not send the the coordinates. It should only store the initial coordinates, and then on `pictureBox1_MouseUp` you send them, because that marks the end of the mouse movement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example of a solution based on **Edit 3** of question.

---

C# Windows Froms Application "*formMain.cs*":

```
using System.Net.Sockets;

private List<Point> lstPoints;

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lstPoints = new List<Point>();
        lstPoints.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        lstPoints.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
    }
}

private void PictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    lstPoints.Add(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Point obj in lstPoints)
    {
        sb.Append(Convert.ToString(obj) + ":");
    }

    serverSocket.Send("MDRAWEVENT" + sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

android service "*SocketBackground.java*":

```
import java.net.Socket;

String xline;

while (clientSocket.isConnected()) {

    BufferedReader xreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    if (xreader.ready()) {

        while ((xline = xreader.readLine()) != null) {
                xline = xline.trim();

            if (xline != null && !xline.trim().isEmpty()) {

                if (xline.contains("MDRAWEVENT")) {

                    String coordinates = xline.replace("MDRAWEVENT", "");
                    String[] tokens = coordinates.split(Pattern.quote(":"));
                    Point[] moviments = new Point[tokens.length];

                    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
                       String[] coordinates = tokens[i].replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(",");

                       int x = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[0].split("=")[1]);
                       int y = Integer.parseInt(coordinates[1].split("=")[1]);

                       moviments[i] = new Point(x, y);
                    }

                    MyAccessibilityService.instance.mouseDraw(moviments, 2000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

android [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService) "*MyAccessibilityService.java*":

```
public void mouseDraw(Point[] segments, int time) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(segments[0].x, segments[0].y);

        for (int i = 1; i < segments.length; i++) {

            path.lineTo(segments[i].x, segments[i].y);

            GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time);

            dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd).build(), new AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                    super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                    super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, bro, but code below is awful like my English:

```
public void mouseDraw(Point[] segments, int time) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(segments[0].x, segments[0].y);

        for (int i = 1; i < segments.length; i++) {

            path.lineTo(segments[i].x, segments[i].y);

            GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time);

            dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd).build(), new AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                    super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                    super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here program call dispatchGesture `segments.length-1` times but only last gesture will be completed because each gesure is canceled by next. From official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService?hl=Es-419#dispatchGesture(android.accessibilityservice.GestureDescription,%20android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback,%20android.os.Handler)): Any gestures currently in progress, whether from the user, this service, or another service, will be cancelled.

Right:

```
public void mouseDraw(Point[] segments, int time) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Path path = new Path();
        path.moveTo(segments[0].x, segments[0].y);
        for (int i = 1; i < segments.length; i++) {
            path.lineTo(segments[i].x, segments[i].y);
        }
        GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, time);
        dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd).build(), new AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
                super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Here we build `Path` as first and then use `dispatchGesture` one time.

If you need await each dispatched gesture then use `Semaphore`, for example, like that (**Kotlin**):

```
    val sem = Semaphore(0, true)
    for (i in 1 until segments.size) {
        path.lineTo(segments.get(i).x.toFloat(), segments.get(i).y.toFloat())
        val sd = GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 1500)
        dispatchGesture(
                GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd).build(),
                object : GestureResultCallback() {
                    override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                        super.onCancelled(gestureDescription)
                        sem.release()
                    }
                    override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                        super.onCompleted(gestureDescription)
                        sem.release()
                    }
                },
                null
        )
        sem.acquire()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/) scripting?

You can save coordinates within specific windows/screens.
You can hold mouseclick pressed while drawing the pattern.

I also have some example code / scripts for you if you want them!

EDIT:

According to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wZQMlmMCR_I) you can use Auto-IT on C#.

**Follow these steps:**

1. Install Auto-IT
2. Add Auto-IT as reference in reference manager (AutoItX3.dll)
3. Then import library that you added with: `Using AutoItX3Lib;`
4. Make new AutoItX3 object called 'auto': `AutoItX3 auto = new AutoItX3();`
5. You can now execute Auto It commands.

This is the complete example for executing a mouseclick:

```
Using AutoItX3Lib;
AutoItX3 auto = new AutoItX3();
auto.MouseClick("left", 78, 1133, 1, 35)
```

With the `AutoIt Window Info Tool` you can check the coordinates you want to use.

Please note there are differences between mouse coordinates modes:

for example: `auto.AutoItSetOption("MouseCoordMode", 1)` will use absolute screen coordinates. See source [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/MouseCoordMode).

For holding the mouseclick down, you can check [MouseDown Function](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseDown.htm)

Comment: This not helped. Your suggestion is exactly what my C# Windows Form Application already makes.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing is to use the continueStroke method to continue the gestures

```
private val isChanged
    get() = x != lastX && y != lastY

 fun move(x, y){
    if (Stroke == null) {
        Stroke = GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path.apply {
            reset()
            moveTo(x, y-1) // Set the starting point and offset it by one pixel to prevent the click event from being triggered
            lineTo(x, y)
        }, 0L, duration, true) // willContinue is set to true, continuous gestures
    } else {
        if (!isGestureExecuting && isChanged) {
            Stroke = Stroke?.continueStroke(path.apply {
                moveTo(lastX, lastY) // Must be the end position of the previous gesture
                lineTo(x, y)
            }, 0L, duration, true)
        }
    }

    if (!isGestureExecuting && isChanged) {
        isGestureExecuting = true
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;

        Stroke?.let {
            accessibility.dispatchGesture(GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(it).build(), object : GestureResultCallback() {
                override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                    isGestureExecuting = false
                }

                override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
                    isGestureExecuting = false
                }
             }, null)
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when lifting, you need to terminate the gesture, Ensure that the next event can be triggered

```
fun up(x,y){
    val up= Stroke?.continueStroke(path.apply { 
         reset()
        moveTo(lastX, lastY)
        lineTo(x, y)
    }, 0L, 100L, false) ?: return
    accessibility.dispatchGesture(GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(up).build(),object : GestureResultCallback() {
        override fun onCancelled(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
            isGestureExecuting = false
            Stroke = null
        }

        override fun onCompleted(gestureDescription: GestureDescription?) {
            isGestureExecuting = false
           Stroke = null
        }
    } , null)
}
```